# The meaning of "seeds that turn around slowly to the ground when they fall"

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sycamore?q=Sycamore) defines "sycamore" as a tree with leaves divided into five parts and seeds that turn around slowly to the ground when they fall. Could someone explain how a seed turns around when falling? Thank you in advance !

Comment: The seeds have 'wings' on. https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/video/high-speed-sycamore-seeds-falling-blue-background-stock-video-footage/142444819 But this is a biology question, not an English Language one!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a biology question, not an English one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sycamore seeds have little wings, so that as they fall through the air, they are forced to rotate. These have evolved so that the the seeds can be carried by the wind further from the tree than normal shaped seeds, and thus have a greater chance of finding fertile ground.

This resembles how a helicopter flies, and in fact in the 1950s there was a British military helicopter called the Bristol Sycamore.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations! I didn't realize this was a biology question. I thought any definition coming from Cambridge Dictionary is language related. Sorry about that .